# How to add elements of a string in a list without changing their types?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, types

I have a string which includes `str` and `int`, for example `string = "qA2"`. I want to add `'q'`, `'A'` and `2` in a list but I don't want to change the type of elements. Is it possible?

Comment: What about `"qA22"`? Should the integer element be `2` or `22`?

Comment: @Selcuk It should be 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method of the `str` class to do the following:

```
>>> s = "qA234"
>>> [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in s]
['q', 'A', 2, 3, 4]
```

Note that this will fail for strings such as `"x²"` because `²` (superscript 2) is considered a digit by the `.isdigit()` method for some reason. The following is safer:

```
>>> s = "3x²"
>>> [int(x) if "0" <= x <= "9" else x for x in s]
[3, 'x', '²']
```

Comment: Oh, OK. It is much easier than I think. Thank you.